# Local windows machine as a git repo for a Linux server

Tags: windows, git

Environment : I can connect to the production Linux server only from Windows environment using a VPN client. External IPs are not whitelisted on the server so I cannot use gitlab or github as repo. So I am having the latest code pulled on to a folder in my local windows machine. Now I have setup this folder as git remote source on my Linux server folder.

What are the changes I need to do on my local windows machine so that the folder can be accessed from Linux server and a git pull will happen smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

1. On the windows client, setup the repository folder (or one of its ancestor folders) as a shared folder.
2. Mount the network folder on your Linux server, how to do this depends on what exact Linux system you have.
3. On the server, you can now use a normal unix path to the repository like `/mnt/WindowsNetworkFolder/repository`.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Will check it out.